# Global variables as input parameters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I doubt whether it is appropriate to use input variables in functions in cases where the input variable will always be the same.

```
mynum = int(datetime.today().weekday())

def somefuncion():
    result = 3 + mynum
    return result

optionA = somefuncion()

def somefunction2(number):
    result = 3 + number
    return result

optionB = somefunction2(mynum)
  
print(optionA == optionB) # true
```

Is there good practice in this respect ? or is it indifferent ?

Answer (score 2):

In your case, it would probably be more appropriate to create constant variables.

```
MYNUM = 12
MYNUM_PLUS_TREE = MY_NUM + 3
```

That way, when you modify the value of `MYNUM` in your development, it automatically modifies the value of all the constant values that are generated from it (here it is `MYNUM_PLUS_TREE`).

The logic I apply here is the following: if a function always return the same value, then it is a "constant function", as in mathematics. Therefore, using a constant variable is preferable.

Comment: Hi  @Vinzee what abou if mynum its not a constan number but come from another process but it doesnt affect the function.

Comment: So it is not really a constant but a variable that does not change and does not affect the functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that you are not going to modify the value of the variable anywhere in the code then you should declare it as a constant and use it that way within the code. i.e. not include it as an input variable.

Python, constants are capitalized ([PEP 8 standards](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#constants)) which helps the programmer know it's a constant.

i.e

```
CONSTANT = "Whatever"
```

in your example:

```
MYNUM = int(datetime.today().weekday())

def somefuncion():
    result = 3 + MYNUM
    return result
```